# What is the sum of the angles a+b+c?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, angle

For reference:

[image: three-circles-inscribed-in-a-right-triangle]

(figure without scale)

My progress:

Circle centers are collinear.
I think that the straight line joining the centers passes through the point of tangency with the side of the triangle. Therefore, the triangles formed will be rectangles and $\measuredangle a$ and $\measuredangle b$ will be $90^\circ$. It remains to demonstrate that $\measuredangle c = 45^\circ$.

Update:

[image: image-after-solution]

Comment: It is not necessary that $\angle a$ and $\angle b$ are $90^\circ$. Also while the centers of the circles are collinear, it is not necessary that it passes through the point of tangency to the triangle. Hint: From the centers of the circles, draw perp to points of tangency. The solution should become clear. Post your progress.

Comment: Is the fact that circle centers are collinear is **given**? Because it cannot be deduced from the figure !

Comment: @JeanMarie I wondered that myself, and you're right, it can't. I ended up constructing this counterexample where the centres are clearly not collinear: https://www.desmos.com/geometry/rnynesyquo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, $\measuredangle b$ is $90^\circ$, but not $\measuredangle a$.

[image]

Hint: Consider the pentagon (sum of interior angles=$540^\circ$). Can you take it from here?

Comment: I didn't understand...which pentagon...can demonstrate...

Comment: @petaarantes from MathLover's image, the pentagon is $QSO_aO_cT$.

Comment: ..i see... But what is the value of angles 2a and 2c?

Comment: @petaarantes , the question asks the value of $a+b+c$. You don't need to find angles a and c separately. I suppose you can see the other angles of the pentagon are right angles.

Comment: @ACB..Grateful for the tip, as I already mentioned my brain stopped on this question...I concentrated on finding the separate angles...but  your result won't work...Why 2c?   2(a+b+c) + 270 = 540 therefore a+b+c = 135 buta+b+c = 225

Comment: Don't take 2b as an interior angle. (See my comment above)

Comment: @ACB..I think I finally understood...2(a+c) +270 = 540 therefore a+c = 135 and 2c because c is inscribed angle and the pentago angle would be the central angle so 2c...As b = 90, 135+90 = 225..Is that it?

Comment: acb ..geogebra...its free..

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Note that $PS = PA$ and $O_aA = O_aS$. $PO_a$ is perp bisector of $AS$.

So, $\angle SAO_a = \frac{\angle P}{2}$

Now what is the value of $\angle TCO_c ~$?

As, $\angle MO_aA + \angle MO_bB = 180^\circ$, $\angle MAO_a + \angle MBO_b = 90^\circ$

Now what is $\angle NBO_b + \angle NCO_c ~ $?

Adding them all up, what do you get?

Comment: I'm sorry for my difficulty but I can't visualize it..." I had a mental block " in this exercise

Comment: @petaarantes you have a question? pls let me know.

Comment: But the answer that you should follow is the the previous one. That is much simpler and faster. I added this answer later showing how you can alternatively add angles to still get to the answer.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'll consider the answer from the ACB who managed to identify where I was getting "locked"...thank you for your patience...

Comment: There is no question of seeking forgiveness :) of course you should accept the other answer as I said before too. That is a lot more elegant answer :) regardless if you want to understand this solution, I can help.

Comment: ..I would like it if it didn't matter..you mentioned: "Adding them all up, what do you get?" but there are so many angles you mentioned that I was confused...I updated the drawing to make it easier...

Comment: I am dividing angles $a, b, c$ each into two parts with the lines connected to the center of the circle, they are not necessarily equal. So first of all, is it clear why $\angle SAO_a = \angle P / 2$? and why $\angle MAO_a + \angle MBO_b = 90^\circ$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129141/discussion-between-peta-arantes-and-math-lover).

Answer (score 5):

Further to Jean Marie’s comment and my own, this is solvable **without assuming that the centres are collinear**. Begin as per [ACB’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4237064/160630), but instead consider the hexagon (not pentagon) bounded by the legs of the triangle and the radii of the circles:

[image: A hexagon bounded by the legs of a right triangle and by radii of three circles tangent to one or more of its edges]

> The radii are perpendicular to the tangents, so three of the six angles are 90°. The angles at the circle centres are twice the angles at their circumferences. Since the latter are $a$, $b$ and $c$, the former are $2a$, $2b$, and $2c$. Lastly, the angle sum of a hexagon is 720°. Hence, $2a+2b+2c+270°=720°$, and thus $a+b+c=225°$.

Incidentally, I’ve had a lot of fun playing around with the [Desmos Geometry tool](https://www.desmos.com/geometry), which I’m sad to say I only recently discovered existed! I made a [construction of the problem](https://www.desmos.com/geometry/dpupw4kvf1) to empirically explore it before I came up with the solution; a variation on that was used for the image above. </plug>

Comment: I thought the fact 'centres are collinear' is given. If not, this should be the accepted answer. (+1)

Comment: @ACB So did I, but after Jean Marie asked about it in a comment, I wondered whether it matters. And it turns out that it doesn't!